# Can I define Default Sort order in LinQ

Tags: asp.net, linq, sorting, listview, nested

If I have a nested ListView, and I'm calling a related table in LinQ, how do I sort it, without resorting to the ItemDataBound event of the parent?

Pseudo Code (UPDATED WITH SOLUTION):

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lv_ItemDataBound" >
   <LayoutTemplate>
      <!-- Product Category Stuff --> 
      <asp:PlaceHolder Id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
   </LayoutTemplate>

   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ListView ID="lvInner" runat="server" DataSource='<%# <%# ((Category)Container.DataItem).Products.OrderBy(p => p.Description) %> %>'>
         <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul>
               <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ul>
         </LayoutTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <li>Item Stuff</li>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Perhaps the method is deceptively simple, but I want the inner **Products** to be sorted by a field. I can't see a way to do it declaratively as LinQ creates this Query on the fly, if I'm not mistaken, and doesn't do sorting.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

Updated the Example to the following:

```
<%# ((Category)Container.DataItem).Products.OrderBy(p => p.Description) %>
```

Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My assumption is that Products is an `IEnumerable<Product>` (or IQueryable).  If that is the case, why not just add the OrderBy method to the evaluation, like so:

```
<%# Eval("Products.OrderBy(p => p.FieldToSortOn)") %>
```

Comment: This may sound stupid... but I didn't even think of that... or to be more accurate... I didn't realize you could do that. Thanks.  Testing now.

Comment: On second glance, this doesn't seem possible.  Can I really Use Eval to evaluate a String Expression?  I get this error: DataBinding: 'OrderBy(p => p' is not a valid indexed expression.

Comment: GOT IT! Same idea, but I did it the following way:
<%# ((Category)Container.DataItem).Products.OrderBy(p => p.Description) %> Seems to Work!