# asp.net Sorting an inner ListView

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, listview, sorting, nested

I've only been using asp.net for about a month now so I hope my vernacular makes sense. I would much rather prefer to use MVC but this particular view page seemingly has to be using aspx and code-behind files as it needs to be "included" in a flat-file CMS.

I have 3 nested ListViews. The first is populated (databound) from my code-behind file using LINQ and works great, gets a list of *years*. Then for the second ListView I call a function GetRecordsFromYear which gets all the *records*, again using LINQ in the code-behind.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv2" runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetRecordsFromYear(Convert.ToInt32(Container.DataItem)) %>'>
```

Next, for each *Record* there is a navigation property (one-to-many relationship with another table) with *Degrees*. The *Degrees* table has a column named "gradyear" which is what I want to sort this last ListView by. I can output this fine by doing something like:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv3" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Degrees") %>'>
```

Everything works perfectly except I can't figure out how to sort this final ListView. I can't use LINQ because I never really retrieved this data, it's a navigation property of the first table *Records*. I guess I could probably just use another function to retrieve the data but it seems silly to have to keep querying the database all the time when I have the navigation property available to me. I don't want a button to sort it, just have it sorted by default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv3" runat="server" DataSource='<%# From o in Eval("Degrees") order by o.gradyear %>'>
```

Option 2:
If Eval("Degrees") is an ienumerable you can do something like

```
  <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstInner" DataSource='<%#  GetDegrees(Eval("Degrees")) %>'>
```

vb side:

```
 Public Function GetDegrees(degrees As IEnumerable) As IEnumerable
    Return From o In degrees Order By o.gradyear
End Function
```

Comment: What you typed did not work (said ")" expected). Changing the uppercase From to from gave the error "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause" so I tried adding a "select o" after it, and that also did not work. I then removed the space between order by to orderby (which I think is correct) and I get this error: "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'object'. 'OrderBy' not found."

I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687134/can-i-define-default-sort-order-in-linq but It doesn't seem to work at all using Eval()