# Asp.Net ListView Grouping - How to order data inside groups?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I've followed this [tutorial](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/607_Grouping_Data_in_the_ListView__Control.aspx) to create a ListView with Grouping. I have similar 1 to Many schema. 
My ItemTemplate contains a Repeater (instead of the GridView). Also, I'm binding the datasource from codebehind using Linq (just as in the tutorial).

My question is how can I order/sort the items that are bound in the ItemTemplate (in the case of the tutorial, sort by Order Name).. is there a way to modify the linq query to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figure it out.. after more intense googling..
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925697/asp-net-sorting-an-inner-listview) (very similar to mine) led me to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687134/can-i-define-default-sort-order-in-linq) and this is what I ended up using this for the datasource of the inner Repeater:

```
DataSource='<%# ((Customers)Container.DataItem).Orders.OrderBy(p => p.OrderName) %>'
```